# Inconsistent behaviour when importing a package interactively vs running as script

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, apache-beam

I have a virtualenv python3.6 inside a VM at `/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij`, with `apache-beam==2.27.0` installed,

and a script `/home/airflow/gcs/dags/advisor/create_dataset/beam_pipelines/dummy.py` consisting of only:

```py
import apache_beam
if __name__ == '__main__': print('MAIN')
```

Running the script I get an error when evaluating the import statement:

```sh
airflow@airflow-worker-7fb797d459-nf8gh:~$ /tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/bin/python /home/airflow/gcs/dags/advisor/create_dataset/beam_pipelines/dummy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/advisor/create_dataset/beam_pipelines/dummy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import apache_beam
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from apache_beam import coders
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from apache_beam.coders.coders import *
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 43, in <module>
    from future.moves import pickle
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/future/moves/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import_top_level_modules()
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 810, in import_top_level_modules
    with exclude_local_folder_imports(*TOP_LEVEL_MODULES):
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 781, in __enter__
    module = __import__(m, level=0)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/advisor/create_dataset/beam_pipelines/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py", line 41, in <module>
    from apache_beam.transforms.display import HasDisplayData
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apache_beam.transforms import combiners
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/combiners.py", line 45, in <module>
    from apache_beam.transforms import core
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 40, in <module>
    from apache_beam.coders import typecoders
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py", line 198, in <module>
    registry = CoderRegistry()
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.register_standard_coders(fallback_coder)
  File "/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py", line 95, in register_standard_coders
    self._register_coder_internal(int, coders.VarIntCoder)
AttributeError: module 'apache_beam.coders.coders' has no attribute 'VarIntCoder'
```

But if I execute the virtualenv interactively and then run the import statement, it works OK:

```sh
airflow@airflow-worker-7fb797d459-nf8gh:~$ /tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/bin/python
Python 3.6.10 (default, Feb  1 2021, 12:07:35)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import apache_beam
>>>
```

In both scenarios, the `sys.path` is the same:

```sh
# --- [interactive run] sys.path

[
'',
'/opt/python3.6/lib/python36.zip',
'/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6',
'/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
]

# --- [script run] sys.path

[
'/home/airflow/gcs/dags/advisor/create_dataset/beam_pipelines',
'/opt/python3.6/lib/python36.zip',
'/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6',
'/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/tmp/dataflow-venvtflya9ij/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
]
```

So my question is why am I getting this inconsistent behaviour?

(Comment aside: the import error makes no sense, cause `apache-beam` is installed in the `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and the coders class has the mentioned attribute.)

Comment: So, it turns out that this does not happen with `apache-beam==2.26.0`. I posted an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11826

Comment: that is some nice write up, like the ones that show how to reproduce

Comment: Yes, thank you for the excellent details.

Comment: I will focus comments on the Jira issue and bring back any conclusions to answer here.

Comment: See the bug: very quickly, I was unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `sys.path` **isn't the same** -- notably your interactive one contains `''` (the empty string) which is your current working directory -- I suspect this is causing some imports to succeed that won't when run as a script